# Auto fill columns in SharePoint library based on SharePoint list or excel where key is file name

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, auto-populate

Is it posiible to fill columns in SharePoint library based on SharePoint list or excel where key is file name?

The situation:
I upload 200 Excel files each month to SharePoint online library. I need to sort and group them by value in added columns. I add this value manually. I would like to fill this columns automatically. I have Excel file and SharePoint online list with needed information. The key is file name.

I tried to:

- build lookup column on SharePoint List but I have to manually chose item from the list for each row;
- build power automate but it works with list not with library;

I will be grateful for your support
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to fill SharePoint Metadata with Excel File Values on Upload using flow?

If true, please refer to https://blog.ion.works/2020/04/01/scenario-fill-sharepoint-metadata-with-excel-file-values-on-upload-with-power-automate/

Comment: Link does not work anymore.